# How do I create a split column in one part of a page?

Tags: two-column, moderncv

What I would like to do is be able to do something [like this](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_classic_green-right.pdf) in the header. I want to split it up. How do I do this?

I know that I could just use the moderncv package, but there are parts of the template that I don't want.

Comment: you can use two minipages or parbox

Comment: @touhami how exactly though? I tried minipages and it only stacks it on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is asolution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
bla bla bla
foo bar baz

bla foo bar

baz bla bla
bla bla bla

foo bar baz

bla foo bar

baz bla bla
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\huge FOO BAR
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]